# Table of Contents: Titles for Parts with \tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I use the `tocloft` package to design the Table of Contents. I wanted to add the word Part before the numbers of parts in TOC (f.e. using `\cftpartpresnum`), but I want to add it only for numbered parts. For example I want to have:

```
Intro ..... 1
Part I Lalala ...2
Part II Lalalala...4
Conclusion ....6
```

Is it possible? `\cftpartpresnum` adds to all parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way: Add appropriate redefinitions of `\cftpartpresnum` to the `.toc` file using the `\addtocontents` macro. (Note: I'm using the [tocvsec2](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) package to add unnumbered parts to the ToC.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}

\setsecnumdepth{none}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}}

\tableofcontents

\part{Intro}

\resetsecnumdepth
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{\partname~}}

\part{First part}

\part{Second part}

\setsecnumdepth{none}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}}

\part{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I can not make it, I copy-paste into LaTex and it gives the following error: "Undefined control sequence \resetsecnumdepth"...

Comment: @Natalia: You have to load the `tocvsec2` package.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works on my desktop at work, don't know why it did not work yesterday at my laptop. But here I have been already using the \tocvsec2 package (following your advise with \minitoc). Should I download manually \tocvsec2 in such case to my laptop? where should i copy it?

Comment: @Natalia: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: Is there the same solution for the `memoir` class for a document which include 27 parts and only the las one has sections and subsections? I tried to use this code, but in my situation table of contents gives first page blank, overlaps the page number and the bottom margin and doesn't go to a new page.