# ToC for Part Heading Levels

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

I use `pdflatex` (TeX Live 2013). I try to make a book that contains 27 parts. It's in Russian. Only the last part has `\section` and `\subsection`. Also I need to have the title of the book on top page header in the odd pages and the name of books parts on top page header in the even pages. For compiling `\tableofcontents*` (without numbers, only parts names) I tried to use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31461/table-of-contents-titles-for-parts-with-tocloft/31482#31482). But it doesn't work fine in my case. The first page turns out to be blank page and numbered with '1', and the table of contents overlaps the bottom margin on the second page. Also it doesn't continue on the third page. It's just "gone".

[image: theres is a screenshot].

I used this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}

 \setsecnumdepth{none}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}}

   \tableofcontents*

\part*{Name of the part 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 1}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}

\part*{Name of the part 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 2}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}
 %-----------
\part*{Name of the part 27}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 27}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}
\section{Name of Section}
\subsection{Name of Subsection}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for your use-case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\l@part{\null\kern-\baselineskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \setsecnumdepth{none}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}}

   \tableofcontents*

\part*{Name of the part 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 1}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}

\part*{Name of the part 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 2}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}

\newcount\partcnt
\partcnt 3

\loop
\part*{Name of the part \the\partcnt }
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part \the\partcnt}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}
\ifnum\partcnt<26
\advance\partcnt 1
\repeat

\part*{Name of the part 27}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Name of the part 27}
\markboth{Name of book}{Name of the part}
\section{Name of Section}
\subsection{Name of Subsection}

\end{document}
```

> [image: tocofparts]
>   [image: tocofparts2]

Comment: the reason the page numbers are weird on first page is that this is a picture coming from a version of the code where I had erroneously `\section` and `\subsection` also in Parts `3-26`.

Comment: It's briliant. Thank you very much. I just have to make line break for long parts' name. But I saw this topic on this forum. I will find it. Thank you once more.

Comment: Hope one day I will learn LaTex very good. :)))

Comment: @filokalos I should have explained that this is a problem arising when `LaTeX` has only headings and nothing else to typeset, it simply does not obey pagebreaks. You can reproduce this by just repeating many times `\section{A section}` with only white space in-between. Inserting a `\null` creates in this context an empty line which gives to `TeX` a legal break point, the `\kern-\baselineskip` compensates for the added vertical space created by the empty line. As for learning very good `LaTeX`, all my encouragements! :)