# Add text before "part" number in table of contents

Tags: formatting, tocloft

I would like to add "Partie" before the part's number it only appears in the text and not in the table of contents. It works for sections, subsections etc. but not part with renew command.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\author{...}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part} :}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Partie~}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Partie \thepart\quad}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Test}
test test
\part{Test}
test test
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: So you *want* it to appear in the ToC? See [Table of Contents: Titles for Parts with `tocloft`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31461/5764)

Comment: yes I want it to appear in the ToC. When I use the same code for sections, subsections, sub subsections andn paragraphs it works fine.

Comment: It shows "partie" in my ToC but it is not capitalized and I would like to change it to "Partie" is this possible? I would also like to change the way parts tittle are formatted. I could do that with `\renewcommand` but it is not working with parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) (section **2.3 Typesetting the entries**):

> In the standard classes the ToC entry for a `\part` is just typeset as
>   the number and title, followed by the page number, with the 
>   `\cftpartpresnum`
>   macro being called before typesetting the number and title.
>   Due to LaTeX ideosyncracies, `\cftpartpresnum` may become doubled in the output
>   if a third-party package behaves differently to that of the default internal LaTeX commands.
>   The `tocloft` package contains specific code to prevent this in the case of
>   the KomaScript classes and for the `titlesec` package; please contact the maintainer
>   to add further corrections if you discover other packages which also exhibit this misbehaviour.
>
> When a standard class is used the `\cftpartaftersnum` and
>   `\cftpartaftersnumb` macros have no effect, but they may do something
>   if a non-standard class is used.

At least with this, we know there is some compatibility concerns between `tocloft` and [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (giving motivation for the `titlesec`-specific ToC package [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)).

Adding

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Partie~}
\let\cftoldpartfont\cftpartfont
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\cftoldpartfont\cftpartpresnum}
```

to your document preamble adds `\cftpartpresnum` just after `\cftpartfont` in the ToC:

[image]

Comment: Note that the redefinition of `\thepart` to include " :" implies that " :" will become part of all references to parts.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after? It now shows `Partie` before the part number, both in text as well as in TOC.

Note: I've cleaned up your MWE a little to focus on the issue onhand. You don't even need the `tocloft` package for this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} :}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thepart\quad}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Test}
test test

\part{Test}
test test

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]